# App Catalog: What's the ReadOnlyAccessToTenantAdminSite group?

Tags: sharepoint-online

On the tenant App Catalog site the group *ReadOnlyAccessToTenantAdminSite* has access. I'm not aware of having added this group myself. This looks like a recent change from Microsoft.

[image: ReadOnlyAccessToTenantAdminSite AD group]

Google so far does not show any results for *ReadOnlyAccessToTenantAdminSite*.

Clicking this group shows:

[image: ReadOnlyAccessToTenantAdminSite AD group details]

Customers need to know what this account does and whether it can or should be used to grant users (e.g. guest users) access to certain SharePoint areas like the app catalog.

Comment: I don't see this group on our tenant app catalog site.

Comment: So far saw it in two tenants.

Comment: Just checked on my tenant & I can see this group now (some kind of `Domain Group`). Tried searching for it in M365 admin center, Azure AD as well as MS Docs>> No results.